# Random values (0 and 1) with condition on each row and each column

Tags: r, random, sample

Hi I am trying to create a dataframe of 600 rows and 18 columns in R BUT:

-each row has to have only three 1's randomly in the 18 columns (for example column A,E,F with 1 and the rest with 0's)
-the sum of each column has to be equal to 100

I am really stuck with this problem :(

Comment: What have you tried so far? Let us know and we can help tweak it.

Comment: I haven't really write any code that is worth to show... I can't find a function that I can specify these conditions

Comment: You have a linear (integer) problem. Check the package [lpSolve](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/index.html).

Comment: The problem has one too many degrees of freedom. This code snippet kinda solves the problem, but the columns are not random.

Comment: This is not an programming issue but rather a mathematical algorithm/problem.

Comment: Indeed @AndreElrico. The problem of *uniformly* sampling such a matrix has been solved in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6635.pdf) and this is not easy. An implementation is available [here](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~jwm40/software.html). I have just tried it and it crashes (I'm using Windows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with the [RaschSampler package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RaschSampler/RaschSampler.pdf).

It implements a MCMC sampler for binary (0/1) matrices with fixed margins. For a MCMC sampler, an initial value is required.

```
# initial matrix
M0 <- matrix(0, nrow=600, ncol=18)
M0[1:100,1:3] <- M0[101:200,4:6] <- M0[201:300,7:9] <- 
  M0[301:400,10:12] <- M0[401:500,13:15] <- M0[501:600,16:18] <- 1
# check margins
all(colSums(M0)==100)
all(rowSums(M0)==3)

# MCMCM sampler
library(RaschSampler)
sampling <- rsampler(M0)

# extract a sampled matrix (not the first one: this is M0)
M <- rsextrmat(sampling, mat.no = 2) 
# check margins
all(colSums(M)==100)
all(rowSums(M)==3)
```

This works:

```
> # check margins
> all(colSums(M)==100)
[1] TRUE
> all(rowSums(M)==3)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: A big massive thank you!

Comment: I don't quite understant the process to get the final matrix but the columns and the rows are random! :) . When I have more time I would definitely read more about this package

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, the sums of columns are 100 but the columns are not random:

```
m <- matrix(nrow = 600, ncol = 18)
for (i in 0:5) {
    a <- ((100 * i) + 1) : ((i + 1) * 100)
    b <- ((3 * i) + 1) : ((i + 1) * 3)
    m[a, b] <- 1
}

m <- m[sample(1:600, 600), ]
```