# Making a random presence/absence matrix (thus boolean) with row and column constraints

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, random, constraints

I am trying to create a randomized matrix in R. It needs to be a presence/absence matrix, such that all values in the matrix are either 0 or 1.

But I also need to specify row and column totals, for example, a 5x5 table where

- the row totals are r1 = 4, r2, = 2, r3 = 3, r4 = 5, r5 = 3
- the column totals are c1 = 5, c2 = 1, c3 = 5, c4 = 2, c5 = 4

---

I was hoping to use `r2dtable()`, but I don't think you can force this function to use only **0's and 1's**. I've tried using `r2dtable()` but end up with values **higher than 1**. Are there any ideas?

Comment: It should be noted that this particular example has exactly one solution. Fill in all columns/rows having 5s with `TRUE`, then...sudoku.

Comment: This is a matrix balancing problem. If the dimensions are not very large, you could use a MIP model with a random objective. If you need many matrices with the same row and column sums without duplications, you could use a solver with a solution pool.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51378594/1100107

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I don't think it's a dupe. If MCMC applies, then the difficulty lies to how to initialize the matrix with margin constraints.

Answer (score 12):

This is a classic (and difficult) problem in community ecology. The `picante` package has a Monte Carlo algorithm based on Miklos & Podani (2004) that randomizes a binary matrix while preserving the margins.  **However**, that algorithm assumes that you *start* with a binary matrix preserving the constraints; it then provides as many randomized matrices with those constraints as you like.

I couldn't think of an easy algorithm to generate a binary matrix (even non-random) with the constraints satisfied to use as a starting value, so I used brute force - I used `r2dtable()` to generate **lots** of matrices and figured that a few of them would be binary matrices.

Here we go ...

### r2dtable to generate a starting matrix

```r
rt <- c(4, 2, 3, 5, 3)
ct <- c(5, 1, 5, 2, 4)
set.seed(101)
system.time(tt <- r2dtable(100000, rt, ct))  ## 0.06 seconds
w <- which(sapply(tt, max) == 1)
length(w) ## 36/100000 (0.036%) are binary
m0 <- tt[[w[1]]]  ## pick the first one
```

If you don't care about efficiency you could stop there. If you need thousands of matrices satisfying the conditions, though, the second stage is better ...

### trial-swap shuffling

Miklos and Podani's algorithm does 'trial swaps' (exchanging row/column pairs that preserve the row/column totals); by default, it does 1000 swaps to randomize a matrix.

```r
library(picante)
results <- list(m0)
nm <- 100000
pb <- txtProgressBar(max = nm, style = 3)
system.time(
  for (i in 1:nm) {
   setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
   results[[i+1]] <- randomizeMatrix(results[[i]], null.model = "trialswap")
  }
)
```

This generates 10^5 matrices in 7 seconds on my machine (which would take about 20 times longer via `r2dtable()`, by my calculation).

### however ...

All of the 10^5 matrices generated in this way, *and* all of the `r2dtable` matrices that satisfy the constraint (only 36 of them), are identical! (We compare by collapsing the whole matrix into a binary string ...) It is possible that there's only one matrix that satisfies these constraints, or perhaps there are a very small number in a very large space so it's hard to shuffle your way from one to another ...

```r
table(sapply(results, paste, collapse = ""))
## 1111100010111111001010111 
##                    100001 
table(sapply(tt[w], paste, collapse = ""))
## 1111100010111111001010111 
##                       36
```

### final thoughts

- if you already have a (possibly non-random) matrix that satisfies the constraints, or if you have a reasonable algorithm to generate a single instance, you're good to go
- The trial-swap algorithm should scale reasonably well (to larger sizes); the two examples presented by Miklos and Podani (2004) are 56x28 and 118x80, respectively. The `r2dtable()` hack, however, will scale terribly. If your real problem is much bigger than 5x5 it will be impractical.  (Simulated annealing or a genetic algorithm might work to find an initial matrix — start with a random matrix satisfying the row constraints and shuffle with an objective function equal to the squared deviation from the column constraints — but I didn't bother to spend the time figuring it out.)

---

Miklos I. & Podani J. 2004. Randomization of presence-absence matrices: Comments and new algorithms. Ecology 85: 86-92.

Comment: Generating initial matrix sounds like transportation problem with binary variables where all edges have weight 1.

Comment: Your deleted answer works (after correcting the typo - the second to last column should be 2, not 1) - but, as you probably saw, is only restricted to integers, not 0/1 values

Comment: yeah `lpSolve::lp` should be used because it has `binary.vec` argument

Comment: To find a matrix that satisfies the constraints, you need [Constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) techniques.

Answer (score 12):

## Update: `igraph` solution

Here is an option with `igraph`, which creates a random bipartite graph with `rsum` and `csum` as degree distributions of respective parties, and I believe it is more efficient and elegant way than the `CVXR` version, and it gives randomness as well.

```
library(igraph)

rsum <- c(4, 2, 3, 5, 3)
csum <- c(5, 1, 5, 2, 4)

mat <- sample_degseq(
  c(rsum, 0 * csum),
  c(0 * rsum, csum),
  method = "simple.no.multiple"
) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "type", value = V(.) > length(rsum)) %>%
  get.incidence() %>%
  unname()
```

and we obtain

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1    0    1    0    1
```

---

## Previous Answer: `CVXR` solution

I guess you can transform the problem into an optimization problem, with row/column sum constraints, where the package `CVXR` might be one option.

**However, one drawback of this approach is that the resulting matrix is not randomized, that means you will always obtain the same result whenever you run the code below.**

Code example

```
library(CVXR)

# Define the size of the matrix and row/column sums
n <- 5 # size of the matrix
rsum <- c(4, 2, 3, 5, 3) # row sums
csum <- c(5, 1, 5, 2, 4) # column sums

# Create binary variables for each cell in the matrix
X <- Variable(n, n, boolean = TRUE)

# Define the objective function (minimize 0)
obj <- Minimize(0)
# Define the row sum constraints
constrns <- list()

# Define the row and column sum constraints
for (i in 1:n) {
  constrns[[length(constrns)+1]] <- sum(X[i, ]) == rsum[i]
}
for (j in 1:n) {
  constrns[[length(constrns) + 1]] <- sum(X[, j]) == csum[j]
}

# Create the problem instance
problem <- Problem(obj, constrns)

# Solve the problem
result <- solve(problem)
mat <- round(result$getValue(X))
```

and you will get a matrix `mat` like

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1    0    1    0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

A less technical but more straightforward/simple way is the **brute force** solution

```
rt <- c(4, 2, 3, 5, 3)
ct <- c(5, 1, 5, 2, 4)
repeat {
    m <- r2dtable(1, rt, ct)[[1]]
    if (max(m) == 1) {
        break
    }
}
```

and it gives

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1    0    1    0    1
```

## Note

The major shortcoming of the brute-force approach is that, it would be ***extremely*** computationally heavy and inefficient when you have larger marginal constraints `rt` and/or `ct`.

About the efficiency analysis of the brute-force solution, please refer to [@Ben Bolker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76040181/12158757) with more details