# Backtracking: List all possible matrices with row and column sum constraints

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, constraints, backtracking

This is a follow-up question of [an interesting problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76039888/12158757). Briefly speaking, the goal is to produce a random binary matrix, where both the row sum and column sum should satisfy with respective constraints.

A bit different from the goal in the original problem, I would like to obtain a list of **ALL** possible matrices that meet the requirement, not just **a random instance**.

I am thinking this kind of constrained problem might be solved using the [backtracking algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76039888/12158757). I tried it by myself but seems its not efficient (I am not happy with it since it's super slow especially when we have longer constraint vectors or many `TRUE`s to be filled in the matrix. *I would like to see **backtracking** solutions that are more efficient and elegant and learn from them. Thanks!*

---

I created the code below, which searches *all* possible matrices that meet the row/column sum constraints.

```
f <- function(rsum, csum) {
  # size of desired output matrix
  nr <- length(rsum)
  nc <- length(csum)
  
  if (sum(rsum)!=sum(csum)) {
    stop("Sum of rsum and csum are NOT equal!")
  } else {
    N <- sum(rsum)
  }
  
  # recursion function that searches all possible matrices under rsum/csum constraints
  helper <- function(k) {
    if (k == 1) {
      mat <- matrix(0,nr,nc)
      return(lapply(1:(nr*nc+1-N),replace, x = mat, values = 1))
    }
    lst <- Recall(k - 1)
    res <- c()
    for (m in lst) {
      l <- c(m)
      zs <- which(l == 0)
      zs <- zs[zs >= max(which(l == 1))]
      for (z in zs) {
        ll <- matrix(replace(l, z, 1),nr,nc)
        if (all(c(rowSums(ll) <= rsum,colSums(ll) <= csum)) && (!list(ll) %in% res)) {
          res <- c(res, list(ll))
        }
      }
    }
    res
  }
  
  # run helper, return a list of all possible matrices
  helper(N)
}
```

When we run the example below

```
rsum <- c(3, 2, 2, 1)
csum <- c(2, 2, 2, 2)
output <- f(rsum, csum)
```

we will obtain a list of matrices (of length `48` in this case)

```
> out
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    1    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    1
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[5]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0

[[6]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[7]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0

[[8]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    1    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0

[[9]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    1    0    0

[[10]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    1    0    0

[[11]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[12]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0

[[13]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    1    0    0

[[14]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    1
[4,]    0    1    0    0

[[15]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0

[[16]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[17]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[18]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0

[[19]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    1    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[20]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0

[[21]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0

[[22]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    1    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[23]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0

[[24]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    1    1
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    0    0

[[25]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0

[[26]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1    1    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[27]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0

[[28]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    0    0

[[29]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0

[[30]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0

[[31]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    0    0    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    0

[[32]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    0

[[33]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    1    1
[3,]    0    1    0    1
[4,]    1    0    0    0

[[34]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1
[3,]    0    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0

[[35]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    1
[4,]    1    0    0    0

[[36]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    0    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0

[[37]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[38]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0

[[39]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1

[[40]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0

[[41]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    0    0

[[42]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0

[[43]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    0

[[44]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    1
[4,]    1    0    0    0

[[45]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0

[[46]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    1    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    1    0    0    0

[[47]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0

[[48]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a essentially a special case of enumerating all possible integral maximum flows. The added generality comes in handy when we make branching decisions and thereby need to look for solutions where specified matrix entries are all zero.

Let me define the flow network. For all k ∈ **Z**<sub>≥0</sub>, let [k] ≔ {1, 2, …, k}. Let there be m ∈ **Z**<sub>>0</sub> rows and n ∈ **Z**<sub>>0</sub> columns, let R : [m] → **Z**<sub>≥0</sub> be the desired row sums, and let C : [n] → **Z**<sub>≥0</sub> be the desired column sums. The flow network has a source vertex, s; for all i ∈ [m], a vertex r<sub>i</sub> ; for all j ∈ [n], a vertex c<sub>j</sub> ; and a sink vertex, t. There are arcs from s to each r<sub>i</sub> of capacity R<sub>i</sub>, arcs from each r<sub>i</sub> to each c<sub>j</sub> of capacity 1, and arcs from each c<sub>j</sub> to t of capacity C<sub>j</sub>.

Let’s assume that there is at least one solution, and hence that every maximum flow saturates all of the arcs leaving s and all of the arcs entering t. Given two maximum flows, their difference is a circulation. What this means is that, looking at the residual network, we can get from every maximum flow to every other maximum flow by repeatedly reversing the direction of a cycle.

I’ll demonstrate. The solution

```
1 1 1 0
1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1
```

corresponds to a residual flow network:

[image: Before image]

After reversing the cycle r1 → c4 → r4 → c3 → r1 to r1 → c3 → r4 → c4 → r1, the flow network

[image: After image]

corresponds to a solution:

```
1 1 0 1
1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 0 1 0
```

To get a backtracking solution, we repeatedly branch on whether a particular matrix entry is 0 or 1. Choose an entry, which corresponds to an arc in the residual network. Copy the network. In one recursive call, simply delete the arc. In the other, choose an arbitrary cycle that contains the arc and reverse it before deleting the arc. (If there is no such cycle, that entry is determined, so we can skip the call.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `R` so I'll outline how to do it then will show it working in Python.

First, fill in your matrix with some type of null values.  Cells will all be true, false, or null.

Second, fill out 4 arrays.  They are:

1. For each row, how many true values you need.
2. For each row, how many false values you need.
3. For each column, how many true values you need.
4. For each column, how many false values you need.

And now what you do is select the row or column which has the fewest remaining true or false to fill in.  Recursively try all the ways of filling it in.  Then recurse.

The point is to move anything close to a forced decision earlier in the logic so that any potential conflicts can be discovered quickly, without having to repeatedly go through other layers of recursion first.

The following could easily be made more efficient.  But it shows the principle.

```
def fill_binary (row_counts, col_counts):
    matrix = [
        [None for j in col_counts]
            for i in row_counts
    ]
    row_yes = list(row_counts)
    col_yes = list(col_counts)
    row_no = [len(col_yes) - row_yes[i] for i in range(len(row_yes))]
    col_no = [len(row_yes) - col_yes[i] for i in range(len(col_yes))]

    def _fill ():
        min_count = len(row_yes) + len(col_yes) 
        is_row = True 
        min_ij = None

        for i in range(len(row_yes)):
            if 0 < row_no[i] and row_yes[i] < min_count:
                min_count = row_yes[i]
                min_ij = i

            if 0 < row_yes[i] and row_no[i] < min_count:
                min_count = row_no[i]
                min_ij = i

        for j in range(len(col_yes)):
            if 0 < col_no[j] and col_yes[j] < min_count:
                min_count = col_yes[j]
                min_ij = j
                is_row = False

            if 0 < col_yes[j] and col_no[j] < min_count:
                min_count = col_no[j]
                min_ij = j
                is_row = False

        if min_ij is None:
            yield matrix  # All rows and columns are filled!
        elif is_row:
            yield from _fill_row(min_ij, 0)
        else:
            yield from _fill_col(0, min_ij)
 
    def _fill_row (i, j):
        if len(col_yes) <= j:
            yield from _fill()
        elif matrix[i][j] is not None:
            yield from _fill_row(i, j+1)
        else:
            # Try yes?
            if 0 < row_yes[i] and 0 < col_yes[j]:
                matrix[i][j] = 1
                row_yes[i] -= 1
                col_yes[j] -= 1
                # Recurse here!
                yield from _fill_row(i, j+1)
                matrix[i][j] = None
                row_yes[i] += 1
                col_yes[j] += 1

            # Try no?
            if 0 < row_no[i] and 0 < col_no[j]:
                matrix[i][j] = 0
                row_no[i] -= 1
                col_no[j] -= 1
                # Recurse here!
                yield from _fill_row(i, j+1)
                matrix[i][j] = None
                row_no[i] += 1
                col_no[j] += 1

    def _fill_col (i, j):
        if len(row_yes) <= i:
            yield from _fill()
        elif matrix[i][j] is not None:
            yield from _fill_col(i+1, j)
        else:
            # Try yes?
            if 0 < row_yes[i] and 0 < col_yes[j]:
                matrix[i][j] = 1
                row_yes[i] -= 1
                col_yes[j] -= 1
                # Recurse here!
                yield from _fill_col(i+1, j)
                matrix[i][j] = None
                row_yes[i] += 1
                col_yes[j] += 1

            # Try no?
            if 0 < row_no[i] and 0 < col_no[j]:
                matrix[i][j] = 0
                row_no[i] -= 1
                col_no[j] -= 1
                # Recurse here!
                yield from _fill_col(i+1, j)
                matrix[i][j] = None
                row_no[i] += 1
                col_no[j] += 1

    yield from _fill() 
 

for m in fill_binary([3, 2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2]):
    print(m)
```